# Swift 4.2 accessing contents of a directory in a mounted volume

Tags: swift, xcode

I am attempting to retrieve the file URLs of all the files found in the root directory of a mounted volume called *crypt_1* in Xcode. When I run the `FileExists` function it returns true indicating that files were found however when I attempt to read the contents it throws the following error below that basically tells me I don't have permission despite that I have set the read/write permissions on the volume to "everyone".

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file “Crypt_1” couldn’t
>   be opened because you don’t have permission to view it."
>   UserInfo={NSUserStringVariant=(
>       Folder ), NSURL=file:///Volumes/Crypt_1, NSFilePath=/Volumes/Crypt_1, NSUnderlyingError=0x600000c52670 {Error
>   Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}

My implementation can be seen below:

```
 do{
        let itemsExist = fm.fileExists(atPath: crypt_1.path)
        print(itemsExist)
        let items = try fm.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: crypt_1.path)
        print(items)
    }
    catch{
        print ("\(error)")
    }
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be much appreciated!

Cheers, Heath

Comment: Make sure you turn your App sandbox feature off or let the user select the directory to be listed